# List<SelectOption> maximum size

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have list of around 400 countries to display in picklist. When adding in List its not allowing. Can anyone please let me know what is the maximum number of rows we can add in List

Answer (score 2):

> The maximum number of entries you can have in a picklist is determined by the total number of characters allowed in the picklist, which is 15,000 characters. Note that each entry includes a linebreak and a return character that are not visible.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=picklist_limitations.htm&language=en